# In Python, how to do groupby, sort the elements within the group and then write the output to a file

Tags: python, file, sorting, group-by

My python data frame contents looks like this:

```
ID       [enter image description here][1]   ROLE       DOB

E548621     MANAGER     1980-12-31
E548622     Dy MANAGER  1983-06-01
E548623     MANAGER     1978-01-05
E548624     SSE         1988-12-31
E548625     MANAGER     1983-05-11
E548626     Dy MANAGER  1985-10-25
E548627     SSE         1987-10-20
E548628     MANAGER     1981-04-02
E548629     Dy MANAGER  1986-09-10
E548630     SSE         1989-02-15
```

My objective is to group by ROLE. Within each group, sort the records using DOB such elder ones will appear first in the list than the younger ones. After grouping and sorting I want to write the output to a file.
I have to generate the output file which looks like this.

```
ROLE        LIST

MANAGER     [E548623 1978-01-05, E548621 1980-12-31, E548628 1981-04-02,        E548625 1983-05-11]

Dy MANAGER  [E548622 1983-06-01, E548626 1985-10-25, E548629 1986-09-10]
SSE         [E548627 1987-10-20, E548624 1988-12-31, E548630 1989-02-15]
```

Please help me to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: Python doesn't have "data frames"; maybe you are using some library or framework?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: If your data is in a file, this one-liner will do all the sorting for you     `sort  -k3 -k2 a.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I think Below query will do fine if not do correct me

```
query_obj = db.session.query(Table_name).group_by(Table_name.ROLE).order_by(desc(Table_name.DOB))
```

Then run a for loop in query_obj to retrieve values as one row